# Assemble a db query from GET requests

Tags: django, get

I'm trying to assemble a query from values supplied through GET requests, is this at all possible?  Here's an example of what I'm hoping to do:

```
def kml(request):
    venues = Venue.objects.filter(
        (Q(neighborhood__city__metro__slug=request.GET.get('metro')) if request.GET.get('metro')),
        (Q(neighborhood__slug=request.GET.get('neighborhood')) if request.GET.get('metro'))
    )
    return HttpResponse(venues)
```

Basically, if I go to `foo.com/?metro=nyc` it'd return all Venue objects for that Metropolitan Area.  If I only supply the neighborhood `foo.com/?neighborhood=soho`, it'd return all venues for any neighborhood named Soho.  Finally, `foo.com/?metro=nyc&neighborhood=soho` would supply any venue meeting both the Metropolitan Area and Neighborhood criteria.

Is this possible?

ps.  Is this essentially what an REST api does?  Am I better off trying to use Piston, TastyPie, or Django-REST?

Comment: Absolutely possible, the Django admin itself does it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django query api is [chainable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters), so you can do this:

```
def kml(request):
    venues = Venue.objects

    if request.GET.get('metro'):
       venues = venues.filter((Q(neighborhood__city__metro__slug=request.GET.get('metro')))

     if request.GET.get('metro')
        venues = venues.filter(Q(neighborhood__slug=request.GET.get('neighborhood')) )

     # and so on...
```